# Graduating with Cohort? What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the following message:

> Hi Sebastian
>
> I hope this email finds you well.
>
> According to our records, you have registered to Graduate for the 28th June ceremony. Dr. [name] thought you might wish to graduate in November instead, to graduate with a MA cohort.
>
> If you wish to do this, you must request so via the Graduations office (by 13th May 2016). [email]
>
> If you are happy to graduate in June you don’t need to do anything.
>
> Please let us know your intentions.
>
> Thank you.
>
> Kind regards
>   [undersigned]

What does graduating with a cohort mean?

Comment: From _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_: "**cohort** _n_ **1 d :** a group of individual having a statistical factor (as age or class membership) in common in a demographic study {a _cohort_ of premedical students}" This is a general-reference question.

Comment: That's ***an** MA cohort*.

Answer (score 3):

[Oxford definition](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cohort):

> A group of people with a shared characteristic

So, the simple choice is:

1. Graduate on 28th June with {whoever is graduating then - the BA crowd?}, or
2. Graduate in November with the other MAs (i.e. a crowd of people with the shared characteristic of getting an MA)

As a slight extension of this, *cohort* has a specific meaning in education, which is why it's used in this context versus any other group noun:

http://edglossary.org/cohort/

> In education, cohort is typically applied to students who are educated at the same period of time—a grade level or class of students (for example, the graduating class of 2004) would be the most common example of a student cohort.

Answer (score 1):

"[Cohort](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cohort): 5. A group of people with a statistic in common, esp having been born in the same year" (Collins).

"Group" would mean the same, but the term is not approved academic jargon; your audience would understand it, and it does not have a background in poorly-understood science, so clearly no university administration would use it.